# Do Gita talks about or mention Upanishads?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, upanishads, gita

Gita talks about Vedas

> BG 10.22: I am the Sāma Veda amongst the Vedas, and Indra amongst the celestial gods. Amongst the senses I am the mind; amongst the living beings I am consciousness.

It also talks about Brahma Sūtra.

> BG 13.5: Great sages have sung the truth about the field and the knower of the field in manifold ways. It has been stated in various Vedic hymns, and especially revealed in the Brahma Sūtra, with sound logic and conclusive evidence.

But does the Gita talks about Upanishads or mention it?

Comment: I think you're not clear about the etymology of the Upanishads. They are not separate from the vedas. They are all extracts from different parts of the vedas. The use of the word veda by default includes those parts extracted by Vyasa and termed the Upanishads.

Answer (score -1):

This distinction between Upanishads and Vedas had not quite solidified yet -- even the Buddha does not mention the Upanishads, but speaks of all texts as forming part of the Vedas. Strictly speaking, the Upanishads are Vedic scripture -- they affirm the validity of the Vedas and are encoded within it. The Upanishads themselves, I would say, consider themselves to be philosophical/analytical/metaphorical analysis of the earliest Vedic scripture. And the Gita is often referenced as "Gitopnishad," implying its Upanishadic status within the Hindu religious canon, although it is encoded within the Mahabharata and not the Vedas.